Ignore missing columns in pandas read_excel usecols
Is there a way to get pandas to ignore missing columns in usecols when reading excel?
I know there is a similar solution for read_csv here
But can’t find a solution for Excel.
For example:
# contents of sample.xlsx:
#Col1,Col2,Col3
#1,2,3
#4,5,6

I'd like to return the following, using pandas.read_excel and the subset, but this raises an error:
pd.read_excel(sample.xlsx, usecols=“A:D”)

ParserError: Defining usecols without of bounds indices is not allowed. [3]

I think the solution is to use a callable, but not sure how to implement it.

it may not cause that issue, but beware your quotes are "smart quotes" “"

@ti7 I wish, but no luck.  Single quotes doesn’t make a difference

At first, make custom function to excel header to iloc of pandas:
def ex_to_iloc(head):
    iloc = 0
    for char in head:
        iloc = iloc * 26 + (ord(char.upper()) - ord('A') + 1)
    return iloc - 1

use ex_to_iloc in param usecols
import pandas as pd
import io
# string example
csv = '''Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5
1,2,3,4,5
4,5,6,5,6
'''
# make string to csv file
file = io.StringIO(csv)

# file to dataframe with only 2 rows to check column length
ncol = len(pd.read_csv(file, nrows=2).columns)

# take 'B'(Col2) to 'D'(Col4) 
file = io.StringIO(csv)
df = pd.read_csv(file, usecols=range(ex_to_iloc('B'), min(ex_to_iloc('D') + 1, ncol)))
print('B to D\n',df, '\n')

# take 'B'(Col2) to 'AY'(not exis) 
file = io.StringIO(csv)
df = pd.read_csv(file, usecols=range(ex_to_iloc('B'), min(ex_to_iloc('AY') + 1, ncol)))
print('B to AY\n',df)

out:
B to D
    Col2  Col3  Col4
0     2     3     4
1     5     6     5 

B to AY
    Col2  Col3  Col4  Col5
0     2     3     4     5
1     5     6     5     6

io library to create a csv file with io.StringIO and use read_csv to show you how the code works in the sample. Since you will be using an excel file, use the read_excel function
Replacing the above task with a function would look like this (Of course, we also need to run the ex_to_iloc function).
def get_df(file_path, start, end):
    ncol = len(pd.read_excel(file_path, nrows=2).columns)
    usecols = range(ex_to_iloc(start), min(ex_to_iloc(end) + 1, ncol))
    return pd.read_excel(file_path, usecols=usecols)

chk with excel file
url = 'https://github.com/panda-kim/book1/blob/main/04titanic.xlsx?raw=true'
df = get_df(url, 'B', 'AY')

df:
 Pclass  Gender   Age     Fare
0  Third    male  22.0   7.2500
1  First  female  38.0  71.2833


Is there a way to modify it so it can handle missing columns.  Like for instance if we fed it B:AY, it would still return everything, but the first column?  That’s the whole reason why I’m struggling

@Jack I modified the code a bit to not throw an error when entering a non-existent header, but to fetch the last one that exists.

Yeah. You can use callable function with usecols parameter in pandas.read_excel. It can be used to filter the columns based on the available columns in Excel file.
import pandas as pd

def filter_usecols(cols):
    desired_cols = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'}
    return [col for col in cols if col in desired_cols]

# Read the Excel file using the callable for usecols
df = pd.read_excel('sample.xlsx', usecols=filter_usecols)
print(df)


I tried that, but it doesn’t work with ranges like “A:AY”

You may have to generate your own list containing A, B, ...AY for desires_cols

Darn even if you convert the excel range to a list, it doesn’t work since pandas passes the column headers to the usecols function, not the index.
Edited my question above.
